# How to monitor and log WLAN status

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, logging, signal-strength

I'm looking for program that can do following:

1. Monitor WLAN signal strength
2. Monitor WLAN signal quality
3. Monitor WLAN speed (e.g. 54Mbps, or 1Mbps)
4. Monitor channel on which WLAN card is currently operating
5. Log the data in csv file or something similar

I need this because I have problems with my WLAN network ... I'm experiencing speed problems, although I have full signal (5 bars in windows). So I'm guessing that there's maybe problem with my signal quality or that for some reason speed is reduced to something like 2Mbps ...

So my thought was: if I could log all the data, I'm sure I'll at least find out why I'm having speed problems :)

So if anyone knows of software that can do these things, please tell me. It should work on Windows 7 64-bit :)

Thanks !!

P.S. I am using WLAN adapter with RTL8187 chipset (I think it's WiFiSky or something like this). It is really powerful and didn't think that I would have problems like this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer The Question above in Simple Words, You can use one of the following Programs:

1: [CommonView](http://www.tamos.com/products/commwifi/)

2: [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

These are Best Solutions to Your Problem.