# Log WiFi status

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I recently installed a WiFi network for a client who uses an app that requires a constant internet connection.  If they drop connection, for even a few seconds, the app will go into a "reconnecting..." mode, and will often lose whatever data they have entered since their last save.

When we tested the network with a handful of users, we had no problems, but when we put all of the users on it (~20 users distributed across 6 open-mesh access points which are designed to handle 20-50 users each) the users of the app started having random, but persistent disconnections.

Most of the time, the disconnection lasts 15-60 seconds, so it is not enough time to diagnose the connection issue.

Some of the more advanced users have reported that their wireless connection has dropped, others have reported that their wireless connection has stayed connected but that they get the yellow exclamation mark and an indication that they have lost internet connection.

I have replaced the router on the system with one specifically rated to handle the network load to no avail.

At this point, I'm trying to figure out where the problem lies.  Is it :

- The actual internet connection
- The ISP provided modem
- The open-mesh hardware
- The computer for some reason jumping between access points.

The only thing I can think of to continue to narrow it down would be to actually log the current state of the WiFi every time there is any change at all :

- Connected
- Which SSID
- Which AP (can we log the mac address?)
- internet connection
- Anything else I might be missing.

Is there a program I can set up to do this logging? Are there any other troubleshooting tips you can offer?

I checked the following questions and they did not have an answer to my question:

- [Log network drops](https://superuser.com/questions/225228/log-network-drops)
- [How to monitor and log WLAN status](https://superuser.com/questions/399118/how-to-monitor-and-log-wlan-status)

Comment: Change the wireless radio channel to 1 in the router.

Comment: I have tried various different channels, and "Auto".  Is there something about 1 specifically that helps?

Comment: With 2.4Ghz you could get bursts from anything, is there a microwave in the employee canteen? For reliability I'd move to 5Ghz if you control the kit, and if you don't I'd start re-designing that application. It sounds like you've need of an AP controller but arent using one?

Comment: So many devices use 2.4 ghz wireless, I have found channel 1 to be the least crowded channel.

Comment: @Linef4ult open-mesh has cloudtrax, their cloud based controller.  Only one of their APs is 5Ghz.  Would this explain the change when there was a sudden increase in users?

Comment: Are the clients homogeneous @trex005?

Comment: @Linef4ult not all of the network, however the ones using the app in question, thus the ones I need to diagnose are all Windows 7+.  Mostly windows 8/10

Comment: @trex005 With CSMA/CA all it takes is one client to decide it needs to TX a load of data for a minute and everyone else ends up waiting, If you're meshing them rather than cabling out to them then each transmission on ANY AP makes two transmissions and holds all devices for that time. You've increased range, but sacrificed performance and reliability to get it.

Comment: @Linef4ult Three of the six AP are wired, and each unwired AP is connected to an AP that is wired.  Still, it's hard to imagine a client monopolizing the connection for 5 seconds let alone 30.  Do you have an idea of how to monitor this?